# Duplicate class org.hamcrest.BaseDescription found in modules jetified-hamcrest-core-1.3.jar

Tags: android, android-espresso, hamcrest

Android studio 3.6

app/build.gradle:

```
 androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.azimolabs.conditionwatcher:conditionwatcher:0.2'
    // Espresso framework
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$espresso_version"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:$espresso_version"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:$espresso_version"
    androidTestImplementation 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-junit:2.0.0.0'

    // UI Automator framework
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.uiautomator:uiautomator:2.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:3.8.0'

    // for test fragments
    debugImplementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.2.0-rc02'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'com.nhaarman:mockito-kotlin-kt1.1:1.5.0'
```

in gradle.properties:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Here my Espresso instrumentation test:

```
import okhttp3.mockwebserver.MockWebServer
import org.junit.After
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Rule
import org.junit.Test
import org.hamcrest.text.MatchesPattern
import org.junit.runner.RunWith

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class FeedbackActivityTransportTest {
 @Test
    fun buttonSend_click_checkRequest() {
        val request = mockServer.takeRequest();
        assertEquals("POST", request.method)
        assertThat(
            request.body.toString(),
            MatchesPattern.matchesPattern("(\"feedback.*\\\"type\\\":2\"))")
        )
    }
```

But I get error:

```
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.BaseDescription found in modules jetified-hamcrest-core-1.3.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3) and jetified-java-hamcrest-2.0.0.0.jar (org.hamcrest:java-hamcrest:2.0.0.0)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.BaseMatcher found in modules jetified-hamcrest-core-1.3.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3) and jetified-java-hamcrest-2.0.0.0.jar (org.hamcrest:java-hamcrest:2.0.0.0)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.Condition found in modules jetified-hamcrest-core-1.3.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3) and jetified-java-hamcrest-2.0.0.0.jar (org.hamcrest:java-hamcrest:2.0.0.0)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.Condition$1 found in modules jetified-hamcrest-core-1.3.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3) and jetified-java-hamcrest-2.0.0.0.jar (org.hamcrest:java-hamcrest:2.0.0.0)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65036282/11180198 works for me

Answer (score 5):

The exclusion of **junit** and giving the priority to **Hamcrest** will disable the oppotunity to perform unit tests with JUnit! That is why you would get an error in Android studio: `Cannot resolve '@Before' or '@Test'` while doing unit tests. The correct way to go will be replacing the **Hamcrest** with **JUnit**!

Place this code to **build.gradle** on **app** level:

```java
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.dependencySubstitution {
        substitute module('org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1') with module('junit:junit:4.10')
    }
}
```

Comment: works for me when I add it to the app module and not the project build file.  learned that lesson hard.

Comment: A problem occurred evaluating project ':manager'.
> No signature of method: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.dependencysubstitution.DefaultDependencySubstitutions$1.with() is applicable for argument types: (org.gradle.internal.component.external.model.DefaultModuleComponentSelector) values: [junit:junit:4.10]
  Possible solutions: with(groovy.lang.Closure), with(boolean, groovy.lang.Closure), wait(), wait(long), find(), wait(long, int)

Answer (score 3):

> I think this problem happened when you add a dependency (as your
> situation **Hamcrest** and another dependency, library, Jar files, etc... is
> using Hamcrest too! but with another version.

If you force your **Hamcrest** dependency in **app Gradle** like below might solve your problem:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-junit:2.0.0.0'
    }
}
```

After apply if you get the same error try to **exclude** like this:

```
configurations { compile.exclude group: "junit", module: "junit" }
```

Comment: Try this :     configurations {
compile.exclude group: "junit", module: "junit"}

Comment: compile.exclude will make you unable to perform unit tests! Please avoid any exclusions, the correct way to go will be replacing hamcrest with junit! 

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.dependencySubstitution {
        substitute module('org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1') with module('junit:junit:4.10')
    }
}