# gradle 8.2 upgrade causing compileSdkVersion not specified error

Tags: react-native

Am being forced to upgrade to gradle 8.2 by app owner but the normally working app fails now with the error compileSdkVersion not specified error. I am pretty sure I have defined it in build.gradle but lost what be the cause of it all. Here are my build.gradle files.

the app is built with    react version 17.0.2 and react-native version 0.67.4.

project/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    ext {
        minSdkVersion = 22
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3')
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        //maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com' }
        maven { url("$rootDir/../node_modules/detox/Detox-android") }
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
            }

        exclusiveContent {
            filter {
                includeGroup "com.facebook.react"
            }
            forRepository {
                maven {
                    url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
                }
            }
        }

        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }

    }
}
```

app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing,
    hermesFlagsRelease: ["-w", "-O", "-output-source-map"], // add this,
    hermesFlagsDebug: ["-w", "-O", "-output-source-map"], // add this,
    bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
    entryFile: "index.js",
    bundleInDebug: false,
    bundleInRelease: true,
    devDisabledInStaging: true,
    root: "../../",
    jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
    jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
    resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
    resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
    devDisabledInRelease        : true,
    devDisabledInDebug      : false,
    cliPath                   : "../../node_modules/react-native/cli.js",
    deleteDebugFilesForVariant: {
        def variant ->
            variant.name.toLowerCase().contains("release") || variant.name.toLowerCase().contains("debug")
    },
    hermesFlagsForVariant: {
        def v -> v.name.toLowerCase().contains('release') || v.name.toLowerCase().contains('beta') ? ['-w'] : []
    }
]

project.ext.sentryCli = [
    logLevel: "debug",
    sentryProperties: "../sentry.properties"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
apply from: "../../node_modules/@sentry/react-native/sentry.gradle"

def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = true

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = true

/**
 * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore.
 *
 * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
 * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
 *
 * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
 * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
 * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US.  Note that
 * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
 */
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

/**
 * Whether to enable the Hermes VM.
 *
 * This should be set on project.ext.react and mirrored here.  If it is not set
 * on project.ext.react, JavaScript will not be compiled to Hermes Bytecode
 * and the benefits of using Hermes will therefore be sharply reduced.
 */
def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", true);

project.ext.envConfigFiles = [
        debug: ".env",
        release: "release.env",
        // stagingrelease: ".env.staging",
        // productionrelease: ".env.production"
]

//to avoid building issues with mahcrest and junit in so emlibraries, likely signaturepad
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59085448/duplicate-class-org-hamcrest-basedescription-found-in-modules-jetified-hamcrest
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.dependencySubstitution {
        substitute module('org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1') with module('junit:junit:4.12')
    }
}



android {
    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
    }
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    kotlinOptions { jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8 }
    // ndkVersion '21.3.6528147'   // The version installed on build machines, see https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu1804-README.md

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.oneacrefund.fieldapp"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 41
        versionName "1.8.7"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testBuildType System.getProperty('testBuildType', 'debug')  // This will later be used to control the test apk build type
        testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk true  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            
        }

        release {
            
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            matchingFallbacks = ['release']
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            proguardFile "${rootProject.projectDir}/../node_modules/detox/android/detox/proguard-rules-app.pro"

        }
        stagingrelease {
            initWith(buildTypes.release)
            applicationIdSuffix ".staging"
        }

        productionrelease {
            initWith release
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
         pickFirst '**/*.so'
        pickFirst "lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so"
        pickFirst "lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so"
        pickFirst "lib/x86/libc++_shared.so"
        pickFirst "lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so"
    }

    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:0.67.3"  // From node_modules

    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0"
    implementation 'com.couchbase.lite:couchbase-lite-android:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'


    androidTestImplementation('com.wix:detox:+') { transitive = true }
    androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation "androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0"

    //implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
      exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }

    debugImplementation project(':flipper-plugin-rn-performance-android')

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }

    debugImplementation ("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-leakcanary2-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}"){
              exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }
    debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.7'


    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }

    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation project(':reactnativesignaturecapture')
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

project.ext.vectoricons = [
    iconFontNames: [ 'MaterialIcons.ttf', 'MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf' ] // Name of the font files you want to copy
]
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
apply from: project(':react-native-config').projectDir.getPath() + "/dotenv.gradle"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```