# Duplicate class org.hamcrest

Tags: java, android, hamcrest

I am trying to import `implementation 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'` in the plugin android project.

**Gradle Scripts:build.gradle(Module:android)**

```
ext {
    junitVersion =  project.hasProperty('junitVersion') ? rootProject.ext.junitVersion : '4.12'
    androidxJunitVersion =  project.hasProperty('androidxJunitVersion') ? rootProject.ext.androidxJunitVersion : '1.1.1'
    androidxEspressoCoreVersion =  project.hasProperty('androidxEspressoCoreVersion') ? rootProject.ext.androidxEspressoCoreVersion : '3.2.0'
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion project.hasProperty('compileSdkVersion') ? rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion : 29
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion project.hasProperty('minSdkVersion') ? rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion : 21
        targetSdkVersion project.hasProperty('targetSdkVersion') ? rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion : 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation project(':capacitor-android')
    testImplementation "junit:junit:$junitVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:$androidxJunitVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$androidxEspressoCoreVersion"
    implementation 'net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:4.4.0@aar'
    implementation "androidx.sqlite:sqlite:2.0.1"
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxandroid:3.0.0'
    // Because RxAndroid releases are few and far between, it is recommended you also
    // explicitly depend on RxJava's latest version for bug fixes and new features.
    // (see https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/releases for latest 3.x.x version)
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxjava:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'
}
```

And after build adding into the MainActivity project and while building getting an error in the MainActivity project.

**Build output error:**

```
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.BaseDescription found in modules jetified-hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and jetified-junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.BaseMatcher found in modules jetified-hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and jetified-junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers found in modules jetified-hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and jetified-junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.Description found in modules jetified-hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and jetified-junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.Factory found in modules jetified-hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and jetified-junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.Matcher found in modules jetified-hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and jetified-junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.SelfDescribing found in modules jetified-hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and jetified-junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.StringDescription found in modules jetified-hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and jetified-junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.core.AllOf found in modules jetified-hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and jetified-junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.core.AnyOf found in modules jetified-hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and jetified-junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.core.DescribedAs found in modules jetified-hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and jetified-junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.core.Is found in modules jetified-hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and jetified-junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.core.IsAnything found in modules jetified-hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and jetified-junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.core.IsEqual found in modules jetified-hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and jetified-junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.core.IsInstanceOf found in modules jetified-hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and jetified-junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.core.IsNot found in modules jetified-hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and jetified-junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.core.IsNull found in modules jetified-hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and jetified-junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.core.IsSame found in modules jetified-hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and jetified-junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.internal.ArrayIterator found in modules jetified-hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and jetified-junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.internal.SelfDescribingValue found in modules jetified-hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and jetified-junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.internal.SelfDescribingValueIterator found in modules jetified-hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and jetified-junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.
```

Comment: Solution was found on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67575923/11704057

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the hamcrest classes are bundled in junit also. So "org.hamcrest.BaseDescription" and the other classes exist on the classpath twice. The JVM will pick the one which appears first. Since this might be non deterministic and the versions might be different, gradle detects this and complains.

To fix this, you have to remove one of the copies one way or the other. In your case, hamcrest seems to be a transitive dependency of another lib, so this is probably not trivial.

These anwers might help:

[Duplicate Hamcrest and JUnit classes after updating Gradle and Android Studio to 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57645919/duplicate-hamcrest-and-junit-classes-after-updating-gradle-and-android-studio-to)

[How to ignore or fix the duplicate classes warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30702059/how-to-ignore-or-fix-the-duplicate-classes-warning)